# Position of node with attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath, attributes, position, nodes

How can i select the position of a node with a specific attribute in XSL.

XML:

```
<document type="async" page="tabTabel">
 <tabs>
  <table>
   <row type="header">
    <column type="text">href</column>
    <column type="number">Mapnr.</column>
    <column type="mapposition">Nr.</column>
    <column type="text">Description</column>
    <column type="text">Document</column>
    <column type="date">Date</column>
   </row>

   <row type="data">
    <column><![CDATA[]]></column>
    <column><![CDATA[10]]></column>
    <column><![CDATA[17]]></column>
    <column><![CDATA[Documentation may 2013 .pdf]]></column>
    <column><![CDATA[Documentation may 2013 .pdf]]></column>
    <column><![CDATA[03-04-2014]]></column>
   </row>

  </table>
 </tabs>
</document>
```

Current not-working XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="tabs//row[@type='data']>
 <xsl:variable name="mapnumber">
  <xsl:value-of select="../row[@type='header']/column[@type='mapposition'][position()]" />
 </xsl:variable>
</xsl:template>
```

I want the index number/position of the column with type 'mapposition'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:variable name="mapnumber" select="count(../row[@type='header']/column[@type='mapposition']/preceding-sibling::column) + 1" />
```

---

In view of your edit, you'd probably want to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:variable name="mapnumber" select="count(row[@type='header']/column[@type='mapposition']/preceding-sibling::column) + 1" />
    <xsl:value-of select="row[@type='data']/column[$mapnumber]" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It counts the columns that precede the selected column (in the same row). There are two of them in your example (text and number). Add + 1 and you get the index position = 3.

Answer (score 0):

This example might help you:

If you've the following XML

```
<row type='header'>
<column type='text'>a</column>
<column type='mapposition'>b</column>
<column type='number'>c</column>
</row>
```

To get the position of `column` with `@type = 'mapposition'`, you can use this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="row[@type='header']">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="column"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="column">
    <xsl:if test="@type='mapposition'"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't really know how to apply this, since I need the value in my <xsl:template match="tabs//row[@type='data']" />